# How to do a sql select query with groups?

Tags: sql-server, select, sql

I have a table with employees and a table with errors. In my application you can assign some errors to an employee. So,
 Employee A will have Error1(type 1), Error2(type 1), and Error3(type2) assigned
Employee B will have Error3(type2) assigned
and 
Employee C will have Error4(type2), Error5(type2) assigned.
Hope you understand the logic.

Now:
I need to make a select which will get count of employees that have assigned strictly errors of type 2(for example).
My case will return: 2(is employee B, and employee C)

How do you suggest to make this?
I was thinking to do a select where to have employee name, total of errors assigned, and total errors assigned which are type2, but i don't know how to make that :|

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I posted a possible solution, but if you post your table defs we could do better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subqueries.

```
SELECT COUNT (id) 
FROM employees
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM errors WHERE type = 2 AND employee_id = employees.id)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM errors WHERE type != 2 AND employee_id = employees.id)
```

As for your query with employee name, total number of errors, and number of errors with type 2, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT employees.name, count(error.id) all_errors, sum(case when error.type = 2 then 1 else 0 end) type_2_errors
FROM employees, errors
WHERE errors.employee_id = employees.id
GROUP BY employees.name
```

Comment: yah, thanks a lot socha23 ;) you saved my day ;) the second query it is exactly what i need ;)